# I am trying to find prime number in list using filter but can't find error as result is odd numbers

Tags: python-3.x, filter

I am trying to find prime number using the filter function in a list but getting a list of the odd numbers. Please help me to find where is the error.

```
def prime(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i==0:return False
        else: return True
L=[x for x in range(11)];print(L)
L1=[x for x in filter(prime,L)]
print(L1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the `return True` within the for loop.

```
def prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


primes = list(filter(prime, range(2, 20)))
print(primes)
```

You don't need to have a list comprehension to filter out items, instead use `filter(prime, range(2, 20))`.

Answer (score 0):

A prime is a number that cannot be devided by any numbre previous to him:

```
def prime(n):
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True
```

Use it in the filter function:

```
primes_less_than_hundred = filter(prime, range(3, 100))
```